# What are good resources to learn HTTP protocol?

Tags: http

Nowadays, I'm reading [Front-End Developer Handbook](https://frontendmasters.com/books/front-end-handbook/2017/). Because I want to be successfull front-end developer. I've read Coderbyte's [guide](https://medium.com/coderbyte/a-guide-to-becoming-a-full-stack-developer-in-2017-5c3c08a1600c). There is also an HTTP suggestion in the article.

I researched for HTTP resources. i've found these links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP

http://httpwg.org/specs/

https://httpstatuses.com/

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/index.html

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-2--net-31155

So, I'm looking for different resources to learn HTTP, DNS, Browsers. What are your suggestions to learn HTTP, DNS and Browsers?

Comment: http is an irrevelant protocol now. Every website has moved to https. Where can I get https tutorials?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*<sup>**Disclaimer:** Don't be surprised if this question gets **closed**. Asking for this kind of resources is off topic here. I would post it a **comment**, but the content wouldn't fit well, hence I'm posting it as an **answer**.</sup>*

---

### RFCs

The RFC's 7230-35 are the official references for the HTTP/1.1 protocol and these document define how HTTP is supposed to work:

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230): Message Syntax and Routing
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231): Semantics and Content
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232): Conditional Requests
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233): Range Requests
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234): Caching
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235): Authentication

For the HTTP/2 protocol, consider the following RFCs:

- [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540): Hypertext Transfer Protocol Version 2 (HTTP/2)
- [RFC 7541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541): HPACK: Header Compression for HTTP/2

It is worthwhile to mention that documents such as [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945), [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068), [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) are **obsoleted and must not be used as reference anymore**.

In fact, RFCs are official references and are not meant to be tutorials. RFCs are like legal contracts. If you are looking for something close to a tutorial, I recommend the next resource below.

### Mozilla Developer Network web docs

The [MDN web docs about HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) is also a credible source.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. The links you shared really made me happy. Where can I ask these questions? Because https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ isn't enough. I want to know everything. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ali  I'm afraid this isn't really an on-topic question on any Stack Exchange site. The next best thing is to find a chatroom where people are willing to discuss learning material. Or find a place outside Stack Exchange. Anyway, the RFC's are a great start because they are the official specs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found chapter one of the O'Reilly book "Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET" to be a really good summary of HTTP. The book in general is aimed at .NET but the initial chapter is not.

You can read it online free: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch01.html

Comment: It's useful. Glenn Block wrote everything that has happened since the internet was born. I downloaded page. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The most fundamental work from what I have read is `The TPC/IP Guite`

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPHypertextTransferProtocolHTTP.htm

you can call the book 'How the Internet works'

btw it's free

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the free book: [HTTP Succintly](https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/http) as a great starting point before deep diving into the RFCs.